# Python Compare strings

Tags: python, string, terminal, serial-port, string-comparison

I am trying to compare 2 strings one coming from Pyserial and the other is a hardcoded messsage. They seem to be exaclty the same but for some reason the function wait_prompt only return 0.

```
 def wait_prompt(device, msg):
        device.write("\n\n")
        device.flush()

        msg = msg + "\n"
        output = device.readline()

        print("\n")
        print("Looking for: " + msg + "|end")
        print("CLI shows: " + output + "|end")

        if output == msg:
                return 1
        return 0

def initialize_router(device):

        print ("Router connected on port " + port[0])

        while wait_prompt(device, "Would you like to enter the initial configuration dialog? [yes/no]: ") == 0:
                time.sleep(1)

        device.write("no\n")
        device.flush()

        while wait_prompt(device, "Line protocol on Interface Vlan1, changed state to up") == 0:
                time.sleep(1)

        time.sleep(2)
        device.write("\n")
        device.flush()
```

While I'm at it, would there be any better way to commumnicate with a terminal over a consol cable ? I saw pexpect, however it does not seem to work in serial.

SOLUTION

the problem was that the output was returning \r\r\n at the end and not just \n like i was expecting. I modified the code to search for only a part of the string to validate the test. Here it is:

```
def wait_prompt(device, msg):
        device.write("\n\n")
        device.flush()
        output = device.readline()

        if msg in output:
                return 1
        return 0

def initialize_router(device):

        print ("Router connected on port " + port[0])

        while wait_prompt(device, "[yes/no]:") == 0:
                time.sleep(1)

        device.write("no\n")
        device.flush()

        while wait_prompt(device, "Line protocol on Interface Vlan1, changed state to up") == 0:
                time.sleep(1)

        time.sleep(2)
        device.write("\n")
        device.flush()
```

Comment: Please add what `repr()` and `type()` return for both strings to your post.

Comment: thanks if found the issue the output was ending with /r/r/n and my test was only /n i modified the code to instead of testing for a full match test for only a bit of the string to be in the message, see above

Comment: I suggest you either delete the question then or add an answer yourself, which you then accept.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem was that the output was returning \r\r\n at the end and not just \n like i was expecting. I modified the code to search for only a part of the string to validate the test. Here it is:

```
def wait_prompt(device, msg):
        device.write("\n\n")
        device.flush()
        output = device.readline()

        if msg in output:
                return 1
        return 0

def initialize_router(device):

        print ("Router connected on port " + port[0])

        while wait_prompt(device, "[yes/no]:") == 0:
                time.sleep(1)

        device.write("no\n")
        device.flush()

        while wait_prompt(device, "Line protocol on Interface Vlan1, changed state to up") == 0:
                time.sleep(1)

        time.sleep(2)
        device.write("\n")
        device.flush()
```